# SyntaxError, if/else, google apps script

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, syntax

I have been working on a script that looks if the value of a cell appears in a named range of another sheet, if the value does appear in Column 1 of that range, I want that row to be selected. In addition, I want a row in the same named range with the Column 1 value marked as '0' to be selected as well.

I have been having trouble at the end with the line 42, I am getting a syntax error with the 'if' 'else'

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Declare ss at a higher scope

function onChange(e) {
    // Check if 'source' property exists in the event object
    const spreadsheet = e && e.source ? e.source : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    const sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();

    var query;
    sheets.forEach(sheet => {
        const A1Value = sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue(); // Assuming A1 is the cell you want to check

        if (!A1Value) {
            // If A1 is empty in the current sheet, skip to the next sheet
            return;
        }

        // Continue with the rest of your code for the current sheet
        const sheetName = sheet.getRange(3, 5).getValue();
        sheet.setName(sheetName);

        // Additional code for the current sheet
        var curriculumAssessmentsRange = ss.getRangeByName("ConnectingMathConceptsA");
        var curriculumAssessmentsValues = curriculumAssessmentsRange.getValues();

        // Get the range where you want to set the formula
        var targetRange = curriculumAssessmentsRange.offset(109, 2, 1, 1);

        // Set the formula in the specified range
        targetRange.setFormula(query);

        // Check if A1Value appears in the named range
        var rangeData = curriculumAssessmentsRange.getValues().flat();
        if (rangeData.includes(A1Value)) {
            // A1Value is in the named range, set the first query
            var queryA1 = '=QUERY(' + 'ConnectingMathConceptsA' + ', "SELECT * WHERE Col1 = \'' + A1Value + '\'", 1)';
            sheet.getRange("B1").setFormula(queryA1);

            // Assuming you have some logic to calculate rowIndex
            var rowIndex = /* your logic to calculate rowIndex */

            if (rowIndex !== -1) {
                // If A1Value is present, select the row with '0' in column 1
                var queryZero = '=QUERY(' + 'ConnectingMathConceptsA' + ', "SELECT * WHERE Col1 = \'0\' AND ROW = ' + rowIndex + '")';
                sheet.getRange("C1").setFormula(queryZero);
            } else {
                // A1Value is not present in the sheet
                Logger.log(A1Value + " is not found in the sheet.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried adjusted different syntaxes to try to align them.

Comment: You forgot to replace `/* your logic to calculate rowIndex */` by your logic to calculate rowIndex.

Comment: Thank you. I got it to run. Still have adjustments and additions I plan on doing for my final product but that finished a big step. I'm new at this and learning as I'm going